# How to extract simple text from a webpage in real time without setting up your own site

Tags: html, web-scraping

I need to access [this site](https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/noaatidepredictions.html?id=8442645) in real time, and extract the next high tide time, to feed it into an app I cannot change (the app expects a URL string as input).

The app is expecting the URL to return via http a simple string of ASCII - not html. So the desired output from that page right now would be "3:30pm".

I know I can write a scraper to parse the html, but I have no way of sending the output of the scraper to the app, since the app wants just a single URL. I would rather not set up my own website to host the scraper and return the results. Is there a way to get the data I need with a single formatted URL? For example, maybe there is a website hosted somewhere that can scrape other web pages with defined rules, and I can point my app to that?

Comment: Doesn't need to be so complex. App could inject js into the current web page. And get the results back. No need to host a scraper on a server.

Comment: Can you tell me a little more please. I don't have any way to edit the final application that takes the URL and expects a short ASCII string. Where/how do I inject js into the current web page?

Comment: Very very very confusing. "Is there a way to get the data I need with a single formatted URL?" Yes, it's at the URL you supplied.

Comment: If you can't revise the application, then you can't inject js. I mean if you have the source, you could inject js into the app's webview. Otherwise you couldn't.

Comment: But if you can't revise the app, how could you force it to send requests to your scraper server?

Comment: What I provide to the application is a URL from which to get the data. That is the only thing I can change about it; so, if I had a scaper server, I would simply provide it that URL. If there was a service on-line that was a scraper server, which took other sites' info and scraped it according to rules you specify, I could give the app the URL to it.